# SQL - Database table mapper - Insert into table, based on select and joins

Tags: sql, pivot, aggregate-functions

This is a life example of the question so you can understand better what we need.

**EXAMPLE**

We have 3 tables

```
cars
*id
*description

car_spec
*id
*car_id
*spec_id
*amount

specs
*id
*name
```

For each car item we want to keep these data:

```
*id
*description
```

And 3 'spec' values located in 'specs' table, based on 'car_spec' table:

```
doors
pistons
hp
```

We want to combine all the required data into one table like this.

```
car_db
*id
*description
*original_car_id
*doors
*pistons
*hp
```

**Sample data**

cars table

```
id | description
1  | 2020 car 1
2  | 2020 car 2
3  | 2020 car 3
```

car_spec table

```
id | car_id | spec_id | amount
1  | 1      | 1       | 2
2  | 1      | 2       | 12
3  | 1      | 3       | 550
4  | 2      | 1       | 4
5  | 2      | 2       | 4
6  | 2      | 3       | 250
```

spec table

```
id | name
1  | doors
2  | pistons
3  | hp
```

**sample result table**

```
id | description | original_car_id | doors | pistons | hp
1  | 2020 car 1  | 1               | 2     | 12      | 550
2  | 2020 car 2  | 2               | 4     | 4       | 250
3  | 2020 car 3  | 3               | 4     | 8       | 400
```

**What we need**

We need to export a new table with the required data.

Can we do this in sql?
If not, any suggestions of how can we do it?

Comment: I think sample data and desired results would help -- as would an appropriate database tag.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have added sample data. Have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically use conditional aggregation to pivot the specs. The following syntax should work in pretty much all databases:

```
select c.id, 
    max(case when s.name = 'doors' then cs.amount end) as doors,
    max(case when s.name = 'pistons' then cs.amount end) as pistons,
    max(case when s.name = 'hp' then cs.amount end) as hp
from cars c
inner join car_spec cs on cs.car_id = c.id
inner join specs s on s.id = cs.spec_id
group by c.id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have changed the 'what we need' section. Have a look and update your answer if needed! Thanks again!

Comment: @jon: the query looks OK. You can add `c.description` to the `select` clause if you like.

Comment: Ok thanks again! Please can you explain, why do we need max function for this? As I understand we should only need the 'case', so we can get what we need by using 'as'.

Comment: @jon: we want one row per car, so we need aggregation. Then `MAX()` just picks the relevant value in each group. We could have use `MIN()`, the result would have been the same.

Comment: What about performance using this on about 7.5m rows?

Answer (score 1):

if 'specs' table is fixed you can use subqueries like this:

```
select c.id, c.description, c.id as original_car_id,
  (select d.amount from car_spec d where d.car_id = c.id and d.spec_id = 1) as doors,
  (select d.amount from car_spec d where d.car_id = c.id and d.spec_id = 2) as pistons,
  (select d.amount from car_spec d where d.car_id = c.id and d.spec_id = 3) as hp
from cars c;
```